# Startup Window Smartgit Won't let me select to standard (workflow oriented)

Tags: git, smartgit

I've started to use smartgit recently and had a question. Even though when first installing it I selected that I wanted to have the standard view, the application set it as log graph. The strange thing is that when I tried to change it to the standard one it appears as if I cannot select it. Any ideas on why I am not able to select this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx596.png)

Comment: The Standard window is only available in the Commercial edition.